# getting product name from global unique identifier

Tags: windows, guid

I'm trying to get the list of all installed softwares, and i want to do it using the Windows APIs only.

This is my code..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"msi.lib")
#include <Windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include "Msi.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR *liProBuf = new TCHAR[39];
    UINT liVal = MsiEnumProducts(0,liProBuf);
    cout << liProBuf;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code uses the function `MsiEnumProducts` which returns the `Global Unique Identifier(GUID)` ,which is the unique identifier for the product.But after this i don't know how to to get the name of the product using this GUID.
How can this be done.

Comment: It doesn't occur to you that you can find the `MsiEnumProducts` documentation on MSDN, and that you'll find other related functions such as `MsiGetProductInfo` in the same place?

Comment: That will only list applications installed with the Windows Installer btw.